# How to do parameter checking elegantly in python

Tags: python

1. check in function

   ```py
   def func(arg: str):
       if not arg:
           return
       ...


   func("")
   ```
2. Check before calling

   ```py
   def func(arg: str):
       ...


   arg = ""
   if arg:
       func(arg)
   ```

I understand that it is more secure to verify within a function, but verifying before calling can reduce one call, is it better for performance?

Comment: The function is responsible for checking the correctness of the passed value. If it relies on the caller side to do so, it *can't* rely on it. Also, it's potentially a lot of repeated code in every caller. — Having said that, it really depends on the situation and exact expected behaviour and is hard to answer with such a toy example.

Comment: In your first implementation arg is not an optional arg, you wrote `args` instead if `arg`

Answer (score 0):

The first option is better.

You don't know when your method will be called again.

If you do another call to your function in a completely different place in your application, you'll have to check it again, leading to duplicate code, and the possibility to forget to check it.

It's true that it uses an additional call, but unless your application is really tight on resources it's going to be extremely quick and you won't even notice it.